# choice between present and future tense

Tags: present-simple, future-time

I have a scenario where I need to answer the below question.

> Is there a verification for Sponsor in IDP?

My answer is below.

> Yes. If the sponsor is deactivated or expired in IDP, subsequently his/her team members *receive emails to change the sponsor details*

A simple *receive* would do here OR *will receive* is the correct choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Receive" is fine.  It's perfectly natural to use the simple present for ongoing or recurring actions, or to describe processes and procedures:

> Every hour the system **checks** to see if there are any new messages in the queue.  If there are, the system **routs** each to the intended receiver and **logs** the incident.

"Will receive" is also fine.  Just be consistent.

> If a sponsor is deactivated the team members **will be notified**, and **will be automatically assigned** a new sponsor.

Side note.  Your question would be properly phrased as:

> Would a simple "receive" do here OR is "will receive" the correct choice?

Remember that questions in English usually start with a question word (*who, what, where, etc.*) or a (helping) verb (*do, would, can, could, should, have, is, etc.*), and *always* end with a question mark.